# Parse a config-file and add to command-line-arguments using argparse in Python

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

I am trying to parse the command line arguments using argparse, and if the user specifies a yaml file for the config-file, add those arguments to the args from argparse

```
import argparse
import yaml
from pprint import pprint


class CLI(object):

    def execute(self):
        self.create_parser()
        self.options = self.parse_args()
        pprint(self.options)

    def create_parser(self):
        self.parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

        g = self.parser.add_argument_group('Device Targets')
        g.add_argument(
            '--config-file',
            dest='config_file',
            type=argparse.FileType(mode='r'))
        g.add_argument('--name', default=[], action='append')
        g.add_argument('--age', default=[], action='append')
        g.add_argument('--delay', type=int)
        g.add_argument('--stupid', dest='stupid', default=False, action='store_true')

    def parse_args(self):
        args = self.parser.parse_args()
        if args.config_file:
            data = yaml.load(args.config_file)
            delattr(args, 'config_file')
            for key, value in data.items():
                if isinstance(value, list):
                    for v in value:
                        getattr(args, key, []).append(v)
                else:
                    setattr(args, key, value)
        return args

cli = CLI()
cli.execute()
```

If my config-file has the following data:

```
name: [Jill, Bob]
age: [21, 33]
delay: 30
```

And I run my code like this:

```
python test.py --conf args.txt --name 'Mark'
```

I get this for the output:

```
Namespace(age=[21, 33], delay=30, name=['Mark', 'Jill', 'Bob'], stupid=False)
```

So, it works, but is it good code?

Comment: When i try to run your parser, with your data file, i get error:
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/kamal2222ahmed/XeedLG

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You don't need a class**

In your current version of the code, it is hard to see what is stored in an instance and how the data flows around the different methods. If you do write a class, I find it clearer to have an init to define the different members but in your case, you could [stop writing classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

Removing the class, you get something like :

```
def execute():
    pprint(parse_args(create_parser()))

def create_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    g = parser.add_argument_group('Device Targets')
    g.add_argument(
        '--config-file',
        dest='config_file',
        type=argparse.FileType(mode='r'))
    g.add_argument('--name', default=[], action='append')
    g.add_argument('--age', default=[], action='append')
    g.add_argument('--delay', type=int)
    g.add_argument('--stupid', dest='stupid', default=False, action='store_true')
    return parser

def parse_args(parser):
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.config_file:
        data = yaml.load(args.config_file)
        delattr(args, 'config_file')
        arg_dict = args.__dict__
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for v in value:
                    arg_dict[key].append(v)
            else:
                arg_dict[key] = value
    return args

execute()
```

The name `execute` probably needs to be improved for something more meaningful.

**The right tool for the job**

To add all the content from `value` to `arg_dict[key]`, you shouldn't use `àppend` but [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

```
        if isinstance(value, list):
            arg_dict[key].extend(value)
        else:
            arg_dict[key] = value
```

Comment: As you were posting your answer, I edited the question. I am now doing getattr(args, key, []).append(v) and setattr(args, key, value). But, I will change to using extend, didn't think about that :)

Is using setattr and getattr better than reaching into the args and pulling out the dict?

The class and function are actually part of a bigger project, this code was to test if it works. Thanks for your help