# Using argparse with parameters defined in config file

Tags: python, parsing, json

I understand that and why using `eval` is generally considered bad practice in most cases (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)). Related questions on config files and argparse don't use types. ([1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79008/parse-a-config-file-and-add-to-command-line-arguments-using-argparse-in-python), [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/81750/partial-implementation-of-parsing-a-config-file-and-command-line-options))

I needed to parse a number of command line arguments and decided to store the arguments, defaults and help strings in a `.json` file. I read the `.json` and add every argument to an `argparse.ArgumentParser`. To specify a type I need to pass a callable like `float` and not the string `"float"`.

To get from the string to the callable I thought of

- using eval
- using a dict to map from string to callable
- using a if/else or switch

and decided to use to use `eval` to avoid hard coding all types.

I have no security concerns because the argument file is supplied by the user and the program that uses this code is targeted at scientists that will realistically want to change the file to add parameters or change defaults. (Also, it is a university project which will never be run except for grading. I handed in a version using `eval`.)

Is there a smart solution avoiding hardcoding all types and avoiding eval, or did I find a place where `eval` is a sensible choice? I was only allowed to use the standard library.

Minimal `args.json`:

```json
{
    "dt": {
        "type": "float",
        "help": "Time step size",
        "default": 0.4},
    "T": {
        "type": "int",
        "help": "Time steps between outputs",
        "default": 50},
    "f": {
        "type": "str",
        "help": "Landscape file name",
        "default": "small.dat"}
}
```

Runnable code, put `args.json` above in same directory to run:

```python
import json
import argparse
import pprint

def setup_parser(arguments, title):

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=title,
                                     formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

    for key, val in arguments.items():
        parser.add_argument('-%s' % key,
                            type=eval(val["type"]),
                            help=val["help"],
                            default=val["default"])

    return parser


def read_params(parser):

    parameters = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return parameters

def get_parameters(title=None):

    with open("args.json") as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
    parser = setup_parser(data, title)
    parameters = read_params(parser)

    return parameters

if __name__ == "__main__":
    params = get_parameters()
    pprint.pprint(params)
```

Comment: 2 quick points; make sure you understand what the `type` parameter means. I discussed this in a recent SO `argparse` answer. `argparse` has a `registries` mechanism that implements a dictionary mapping between strings and functions for this parameter.

Comment: References to hpaulj's comment: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008758/parsing-boolean-values-with-argparse/19233287#19233287); [type=](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type) can take any callable that takes a single string argument and returns the converted value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like the `eval` here anywhere for the usual reasons. I think you have two better options here:

## Find the right type within all builtin types

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3222774/620382 (use `builtins` for python3)

## Use the `type` of the default value from json.

Json types are properly translated to python. `type(val['default'])` will provide this type. You can check with `__name__ == val['type']` if you want to keep the redundancy. Of course you then should make sure to use `"default": 0.0` if the value should be float.

Comment: I really like the idea to use the type of the default value. It avoids eval and the user does not need to think about data types.

Answer (score 6):

The use of a `json` file/expression as a source for defining `argparse` arguments is clever, and I think sound.  `ipython` defines many of its commandline arguments from values in a `config` file.

I commented that we need to be careful about what `type` does.  It's a frequent point of confusion.  It is a callable, usually a function, that takes a string, and converts it to the kind of value you want in the `args` namespace.  Its relation to builtin types and the the Python `type` function is only tangential.

`int` and `float` work because those functions take a string and return a desired value (or raise an error).  `bool` does not because it does not take string and return a `True/False` (try `bool('False')`.

`argparse` has an undocumentated `registries` mechanism that maps from strings to callables.  Mostly it is used for the `action` parameter, but can also be used with `type`.  Basically it's a dictionary.

Here's a quick session to illustrate its use.

```
In [2]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
```

`parser.register` is an undocumented method, used internally, but available to the user (no `_`):

```
In [3]: parser.register?
Type:       instancemethod
...
File:       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/argparse.py
Definition: parser.register(self, registry_name, value, object)
Docstring:  <no docstring>
```

It sets an entry in a dictionary that the `parser` owns.  Notice all the familiar `action` values.  This maps from those strings to the `Action` subclasses.  There is only one `type` entry, the default case that does nothing (leaves a string unchanged).

```
In [4]: parser._registries
Out[4]: 
{'action': {None: argparse._StoreAction,
  'append': argparse._AppendAction,
  'append_const': argparse._AppendConstAction,
  'count': argparse._CountAction,
  'help': argparse._HelpAction,
  ...
 'type': {None: <function argparse.identity>}}
```

So let's add some entries to the register:

```
In [5]: parser.register('type','float',float)
In [6]: parser.register('type','int',int)
In [7]: parser.register('type','str',None)
```

and create some Actions to use them:

```
In [8]: parser.add_argument('-i',type='int')
....
In [9]: parser.add_argument('-f',type='float')
...
In [10]: parser.add_argument('-s',type='str')
... 
ValueError: None is not callable
```

Oops, it didn't like my `None`.  I was intending the `None` to map on to the existing `None` mapping in the registries, but it does not do that kind of double mapping.

I think the `str()` function will work.  It takes a string and returns it unchanged.  The `argparse` `identity` is more like a do nothing `lambda x:x`.

```
In [12]: str('astirng')
Out[12]: 'astirng'

In [13]: parser.register('type','str',str)

In [14]: parser.add_argument('-s',type='str')
Out[14]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['-s'], dest='s', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type='str', choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
```

Now let's test:

```
In [15]: parser.parse_args('-i 1 -f 23 -s 23'.split())
Out[15]: Namespace(f=23.0, i=1, s='23')
```

If you don't want to use `register`, I'd recommend a dictionary over `eval`.  As another answer notes there aren't that many `types`, and you have more control over the translation.

A recent SO question suggests on potential difficulty with your json-argparse mapping.  Not all Actions take a `type` parameter`.  Your set of parameters is fine for the default`store`action.  But a`store_true`action raises an error if you give it a`type` parameter.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574270/typeerror-init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-type-in-argparse

---

I'd prefer calling `add_argument` with:

```
parser.add_argument(*args, **kwargs)
```

and build up `args` as a list, and `kwargs` as a dictionary. For example instead of :

```
for key, val in arguments.items():
    parser.add_argument('-%s' % key,
                        type=eval(val["type"]),
                        help=val["help"],
                        default=val["default"])
```

use something like:

```
for key, val in arguments.items():
    args = ['-%s'%key]
    kwargs = {<some defaults>}
    kwargs.update(val)
    parser.add_argument(*args, **kwargs)
```

This would allow me to use json strings like

'foo': {'action': 'store_true',
           'help': 'True/False values'},
   'bar': {'type': 'int',
           'default': 2},
   'baz': {'nargs': '+',
           'help': 'multiple values'}

I haven't tested this yet, but if I've got it right, it would give more flexibility.  Internally `argparse` uses `**kwargs` a lot to handle the large numbers of parameters that its methods take.

Comment: Just wondering how do you get the `In [1]` `Out[1]` things? And this is some amazing stuff +1.

Comment: The line numbering comes from an `ipython` shell.  I use it so much for testing ideas that I forget it isn't the default environment.

Answer (score 1):

So as it seems that you want to get rid of `eval`, or as some people call it evil.

One way to do that is to use the builtins.
The `__builtins__` contains all the defalt types / function / classes in a normal Python script.
For example, if you fear that a function has been overwritten you can use `__builtins__` to use the standard one.

```
>>> max = 'max'
>>> max
'max'
>>> __builtins__.max(1, 2)
2
```

However how can we use this to make your program safer?

First I checked the `type` of object `str` was.
This way we know a way to filter the results.

However a lot of `__builtins__` were an instance of `type`.
And so I done a check on if things were new-style classes,
which means that the inherit from `object`.

However it would also return every exception.
And so you need to filter against if it is a sub-class of `BaseException`

```
>>> type(str)
<class 'type'>
>>> isinstance(str, type)
True
>>> issubclass(str, object)
True
>>> issubclass(str, BaseException)
False
>>> issubclass(BaseException, object)
True
```

And so to have safer types, you can make a dictionary comprehension.
That filters by 2 things. The first to short circuit the second check.

```
allowed = {
    key: value
    for key, value in __builtins__.__dict__.items()
    if isinstance(value, type) and not issubclass(value, BaseException)
}
```

This allows some 'non-types' through, but it's pretty concise.
Some non-type:

- `__loader__`
- `classmethod`
- `enumerate`
- `filter`
- `super`

---

However just using `__builtins__` has the drawback, that you can't use custom types.
But there is a way to get passed that!

```
>>> class MyClass:pass
... 
>>> {
...     key: value
...     for key, value in globals().items()
...     if isinstance(value, type) and not issubclass(value, BaseException)
... }
{'MyClass': <class '__main__.MyClass'>, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>}
```

**Note**: `__loader__` is not part of globals in files.

And so to get a way safer version of `evil` you can:

```
_globals = {}
_globals.update(globals())
_globals.update(__builtins__.__dict__)
allowed = {
    key: value
    for key, value in _globals.items()
    if isinstance(value, type) and not issubclass(value, BaseException)
}
```

---

Now onto the rest of your code.

You should limit the amount of characters per line.
As here your `argparse` is going out of the screen.
One way to ammend this is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=title,
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
)
```

You can use more characters, `val` is short for `value`, but the latter is easier to understand.
It's not that big a deal, but it's a bit nicer.

You use the old style `%` format.
This is advised against, due to bugs, and edge-cases.
Instead use `str.format`. E.g. `'-{}'.format(key)`

You have *too much* white-space.
You don't need a newline after every function definition, and you don't need one after every 'block'.
I would write `set_parser` as:

```
def setup_parser(arguments, title):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=title,
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
    )
    for key, value in arguments.items():
        parser.add_argument(
            '-%s' % key,
            type=allowed[value["type"],
            help=value["help"],
            default=value["default"]
        )
    return parser
```

Otherwise your code's pretty good.

Comment: Your comment on `%` format made me realise that I can simply do string concatenation `"-" + key` in this case.
Interesting that your code with *reduced* white-space is a line longer and equal length if I conform to 79 character lines. (I use pylint's standard 100).

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, except that you don't need to define a "Type"; we can pass `type=type(value["default"]`) instead, it will determine the type based on the default value:

```
def setup_parser(arguments, title):
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=title,
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
)
for key, value in arguments.items():
    parser.add_argument(
        '-%s' % key,
        type=type(value["default"]),
        help=value["help"],
        default=value["default"]
    )
return parser
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly don't have any security concerns, why not store the data in a python dict in a .py file that gets imported. Then "type" can be the actual type instead of a string--no need to map strings to types.

args.py:

```
config = {
       "dt": {
           "type": float,
           "help": "Time step size",
           "default": 0.4},
       "T": {
           "type": int,
           "help": "Time steps between outputs",
           "default": 50},
       "f": {
           "type": str,
           "help": "Landscape file name",
           "default": "small.dat"}
   }
```

main code:

```
import argparse
import pprint

import args          


def setup_parser(arguments, title):

    for key, val in arg.config.items():  
        parser.add_argument('-' + key, **val)

    return parser


def get_parameters(title=None):
    parser = setup_parser(data, title)
    parameters = vars(parser.parse_args())

    return parameters
```